# How do I fix my Grub2 "permanently"? (No partition found)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I currently have a Windows 10 - Ubuntu 14.04.3 Dual boot on my PC.
 The other day I was creating a partition using Disk management from Windows, and then the software crashed. I had to force shut down and when I restarted, what is see is something in the lines `No partition found` and a grub rescue prompt.

So, I check for a solution online, and finally found one. It said that I should direct the grub rescue to the grub file in my Ubuntu partition and gave me some steps. So I followed. This is what I do to get to the boot loader now:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub/
insmod normal
normal
```

The problem now is: I have to do this every goddamn time I turn on this thing. How should I command grub rescue to automatically find the file like it normally does?

Comment: are you able to boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Do not create partitions with Windows. Use gparted. Only use Windows tools to resize NTFS partitions. Windows is even known to rewrite partition table without Linux partitions if BIOS/MBR install. But may be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  You can run from Live installer or if you can boot, from inside your install.

Comment: @Kenpachi : Yeah.. After I type the above commands, I get my boot loader like normal times. Then I can switch between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred : Yeah.. I heard it from my friends many times. But somehow gparted's interface looks kinda complicated and risky 'coz I don't understand many things there. But now I learnt my lesson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1:

Try running `sudo update-grub`. If that does not fix the problem, then try option 2:

## Option 2:

1. Create a file `/etc/grub.d/windows10_custom`

> ```
> menuentry "Windows 10" {
> set root=(hd0,msdos6)
> set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub/
> insmod normal
> normal
> }
> ```

2. Run `sudo update-grub`

## References

[Ubuntu's guide to building custom menus for grub 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus)